# Textarea not react on .change()?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-ui

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var keyUpTime = 0;                  
    var t = 0;
    var executeAfterOneSecond = false;
    $('#source').keyup(function(){
        if(executeAfterOneSecond == false){
            executeAfterOneSecond = true;
            t = setTimeout(function(){
                executeAfterOneSecond = false;
                sendValue($('#source').val());                          
                }, 600);
            }                                   
        keyUpTime = $.now();
        setTimeout(function(){
            if($.now() - keyUpTime >= 200) {
                clearTimeout(t);
                executeAfterOneSecond = false;
                sendValue($('#source').val());          
                }           
            },200);
    });
});

<textarea id="source" name="text" wrap="soft" tabindex="0" dir="ltr" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="box-sizing: border-box; overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: auto; padding-right: 20px; " class="oggy-textarea">
                                </textarea>
```

Well, I want my code works on change(); [$('#source').change(function(){---});], not on keyup(), but it doesn't. I tried with bind() but nothing. What's wrong?

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't work? What experiment did you perform, what result did you expect and what actually happened?

Comment: I added a whole bunch of edits to my answer - you might find them helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

The Change event only happens when the `input` control loses `focus` - hence why it's not firing.

See here under notes: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_change.asp

You have to go with the `keyUp`, `keyPress` or `keyDown`

you could really clean up your methods too. Something like the following might be more stable.

This will call `sendValue()` after 1 second after the last keyup. Takes your 22 lines down to 6 :)

Here is the code below as an example if [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QvZz7/)

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#source").keyup(function(){
         clearTimeout(this.timer);
         this.timer = setTimeout(function() {sendValue($("#source").val());}, 1000);
      });

   });
```